# Github action expression does not allow to compare or use ! (not) operator

Tags: github-actions

I have 3 steps:

```
- name: echo1
  run: echo ${{ steps.stepid.outputs.value }}
    
- name: echo2
  run: echo ${{ steps.stepid.outputs.value == false }}

- name: echo3
  run: echo ${{ !steps.stepid.outputs.value }}
```

And all outputs are "false". How can I revert my false value to true?

Comment: Could you share the whole workflow .yaml file in your question please?

Comment: Is it not because the outputs is an array of output and the value should be referred to the value you set to a specific output, like if you do: `::set-output name=myoutput::false` you can check it with `steps.stepid.outputs.myoutput.value` (if boolean is supported). As GuiFalourd said, it would be better to share the whole workflow to be able to help.

Comment: If you just want to validate the step outcome, I'd suggest you use `steps.stepid.outcome` and `steps.stepid.outcome == 'failure'` or `steps.stepid.outcome == 'success'`.

Answer (score 1):

The proper answer is that the boolean value from the previous step actually becomes a string for the current one.
Therefore `...output.value == 'false'` should be used instead of `...output.value == false`

Comment: this is the proper answer. please use

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution that needs mentioning: marshal the value using GitHub's built-in `toJSON` and `fromJSON` functions.

```
...
steps:
  - name: I produce a boolean output
    id: output_producer
    shell: bash
    run: |
      if [[ $RANDOM > 100 ]]; then i=true; else i=false; fi
      echo "::set-output name=boolean_output::${{ toJSON($i) }}"
      echo "::set-output name=integer_output::${{ toJSON($i) }}"
  - name: I only run conditionally
    if: fromJSON(steps.output_producer.outputs.boolean_output) 
    shell: bash
    run: |
      echo "Ran successfully!"
  - name: I run always
    if: always()
    shell: bash
    run: |
      echo ${{ fromJSON(steps.output_producer.outputs.integer_output) }}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It's pretty difficult but will try